# Regexp matches after white-space on this example

Tags: javascript, regex

`/.n/g` matches *"nope, **an** apple is **on** the tree"*

Notice that the '*n*' of '*nope*' is unaffected because:

```
(The decimal point) matches any single character except the
newline characters: \n \r \u2028 or \u2029. ([\s\S] can be
used to match any character including newlines.)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

.

But the problem is that I do NOT want to match the 'n' that comes after a white-space:

`/.n/g` matches *"I don't want to match this **n**!"*

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: by saying "respect" are you saying that you do **not** want to match a `n` found after a space/whitespace?

Comment: yes, sorry to don't be that clear, I will try to update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regexp like `/[\S]n/g` (or the shorter, less readable, version `/\Sn/g` will provide you with the functionality you asked for. `\S` will match any character that isn't a whitespace.

Remember that `\S` will not match `" "`, `"\t"`, etc. if you just want to ignore "real" spaces     `/[^ ]n/g` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Although javascript regexps derive from Perl, they [do not implement](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-conditionals) conditional matching and lookarounds. I believe, your only option is to exclude the whitespace family as @refp and @TudorConstantin have already suggested: `/\Sn/g`.

Answer (score 0):

try by using the character class that excludes the whitespace family:

```
/[\S]n/g
```

Comment: @ajax333221 it's because his previous snippet (before editing) also contained `\s` inside the brackets, which means it will match any whitespace character. And since he used `\s` **and** `\S` it matched any character, exactly like a `.`.

Comment: I think that 'refp' explained it better, plus I think he answered correct before your edit... I will accept his ans

Comment: @refp - `\s` **and** `\S` is a little more than just `.` - it also matches newline characters, but you are right mainly - I proposed that regex because I understood that he wants all the characters before `n` to match

Comment: @TudorConstantin Yes, you are correct. I blame lack of sleep and too much coffee, thank you for pointing that out to me.. I feel embarrassed to be honest. 06:19 am, 32 hours without sleep makes refp tired.

Comment: @refp, why you haven't sleet on 32 hours? O_o

Comment: @refp - right - why haven't you sleep? In Romania is 7:28 am, but I had a wonderful sleep :D